# Javascript: display/call images from google drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

I'm trying trying to display images when the user selects an item and then clicks  the button, however the images location are stored in google drives, how can i call this images from google drive.below is my code and here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4EvXL/

```
<form action="" method="get">
 <select name="code" id="code">
 <option value="a">Image1</option>
 <option value="b">Image2</option>
 <option value="c">Image3</option>
 <option value="d">Image4</option>
 <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Show Image" class="button">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#btn1').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     $('#img1').show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a public folder and place the images there. Then you can just use the URL from the folder, like:

```
http://googledrive.com/host/<folder_Name>/<file_name>
```